# General rule for new decision boundary after normalizing data?

Tags: classification, normalization

Many classifiers, such as Support Vector Machines (SVMs) generalize better when the input features are normalized. Is there, however, an intuitive visualization/explanation of the map of the original decision boundary (before normalization) to the new decision boundary (after normalization)?